# Unable to change image from one image to another on onClick( ) event android

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

I have a dynamic list from server database in listview. In each row of list, I've added two images where one of them is clickable which is in-built android **Star Off** image. Now when user clicks on Star Off image, that image should change to **Star On**. For this, I've set onClickListener on image but I am getting error on onClickListener. I've also tried onTouchListener but got same error. Here is my full code below :

Category.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Category extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    String url;
    String CompName,CompID;
    Strings st1=new Strings();
    TextView text;
    ImageView star;

    ListView list;
    //List<RowItem> rowItems;

    TextView txt;
    int k=0;
    int po;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        ActionBar action=getActionBar();
        action.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        action.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        CompID = intent.getStringExtra("CompID");
        url=st1.getUrl();
        connect(CompID);

        star=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        star.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg0==star)
                {
                    star.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void connect(String compID2) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String data;
        List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<String> r1=new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_text_black,R.id.list_item,r);

        final ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        //CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
        try 
        {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url+"Retrive.php?q=comp&p="+URLEncoder.encode(compID2,"UTF-8"));
                //HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://demo.tugain.com/tapme/retrieveVendor.php?q="+URLEncoder.encode(abc,"UTF-8"));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                data=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.e("STRING", data);

                try 
                {
                   JSONArray json=new JSONArray(data);
                   for(int i=0;i<json.length(); i++)
                   {
                        JSONObject obj=json.getJSONObject(i);

                        CompName=obj.getString("fldName");//Name of the vendor.
                        CompID=obj.getString("fldVid");//ID of the vendor. 

                        Log.e("STRING", CompName);
                        Log.e("STRING",CompID);

                        r.add(CompName);
                        r1.add(CompID);
                        //star=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favorite+k);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);

                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>list1=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                        HashMap<String,String>item=new HashMap<String, String>();
                        item.put("CompName",CompName);
                        item.put("CompID",CompID);
                        list1.add(item);

                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),list1+"",5000).show();


                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id) 
                            {
                            String a=Integer.toString(position);
                            po=position;
                                Log.e("selected company's id is : ",a);
                                String selected=r1.get(position);

                                //String selected=(String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                Log.e("selected company's id is : ",selected);
                                Intent i1=new Intent(Category.this,Chatting.class);
                                //i1.putExtra("CompID", selected);
                                startActivity(i1);
                            }
                        });
                        String df=r1.get(po);
                        Log.e("dfsf", df);
                   }
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.category, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Category.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables,MangledCRLF,ContentDescription,DisableBaselineAlignment,InefficientWeight" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_text_black.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="30dp"
            android:maxWidth="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:text="Just Test"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

```
08-21 15:53:41.942: D/AndroidRuntime(23553): Shutting down VM
08-21 15:53:41.942: W/dalvikvm(23553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer/com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.Category}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.Category.onCreate(Category.java:66)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-21 15:53:41.962: E/AndroidRuntime(23553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the cause, it can be tell only when seeing the log cat. but try `ImageButton` insted of `ImageView` and

```
star=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.favorite);
star.setTag("star");
    star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(arg0.getTag().toString().equals("star"))
                    {
                        star.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
                    }
                }
            });
```

try it out.

Comment: please check the edited thing, use settag and get tag or compare with id inside click()

Comment: do a toast inside the onClick(View arg0){} and show the arg0.gettag().tostring() value and check it.

Comment: application crash just before onClick at star.setTag("star");

Comment: Sorry!! if it is the problem with get tag, then (View arg0) may be null,  are you using it in main thread (UI thread) itself? if you cannot fix it , then i will past code in my eclipse.

Comment: you are calling connect(CompID); in UI main thread, Thats the issue.... try comment the code and check.

Comment: Call that in separate thread, network communication must done on separate thread, you can use asynctask and do the network call in doinbackground() and update the UI in onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

change your if condition from
 this:

```
if(arg0 == star){
// TODO
}
```

To this:

```
if(arg0.getId() == R.id.star){
// TODO
}
```

Comment: Works only when if(arg0.getId() == R.id.star){
// TODO
}

Answer (score 0):

```
star.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg0==star)
                {
                     star.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    star.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
                }
            }
        });
```

so that i can show effect of your image

Answer (score 0):

You can user Picasso Picasso

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

ImageView iv_user_action;
iv_user_action=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iv_user_action);

Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.plus).fit().placeholder(R.drawable.plus).into(iv_user_action);
```